# Have more than one animation in a pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I dont know how to not have just a constant running animation as you can see all the tutorials I follow just lead me to load in one animation in the Player() Class.  Right now my images load in pygame.image.load is just a running animation. If there is a fix to add different animations with different key inputs that would help.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os

'''
Variables
'''

worldx = 900
worldy = 500
fps = 30
ani = 4
world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx, worldy])

BLUE = (25, 25, 200)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (254, 254, 254)
ALPHA = (0, 255, 0)

'''
Objects
'''


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    Spawn a player
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1, 5):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('/home/pi/Desktop/Work/Python work/Game/Resources/Sprites/santasprites/png', 'Run' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
            img.convert_alpha()  # optimise alpha
            img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (400, 500))
            img.set_colorkey(BLACK)  # set alpha
            self.images.append(img)
            self.image = self.images[0]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def control(self, x, y):
        """
        control player movement
        """
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        """
        Update sprite position
        """
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey
        if self.rect.right > worldx:
            self.rect.right = worldx
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        # moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.frame // ani], True, False)

        # moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3*ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.frame//ani]


'''
Setup
'''

backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('/home/pi/Desktop/Work/Python work/Game/Resources/Backdrops', 'backdrop.png'))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Santas Revenge')
backdropbox = world.get_rect()
main = True

player = Player()  # spawn player
player.rect.x = 0  # go to x
player.rect.y = 10  # go to y
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
steps = 10

'''
Main Loop
'''

while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            try:
                sys.exit()
            finally:
                main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                try:
                    sys.exit()
                finally:
                    main = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.control(-steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.control(steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                print('jump')

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                player.control(steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                player.control(-steps, 0)

    world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)
    player.update()
    player_list.draw(world)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: based on direction use a different set of frames

Answer (score 0):

In order to add more animations, you need to load more images, for each animation. Then, you need to change your update function so it knows whether to load the running  or the walking images for display.

First, you need separate lists for each animation (or you could do something fancy with nested lists). Then, each list needs to be loaded with the right images. An example of what it might look like:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('/home/pi/Desktop/Work/Python work/Game/Resources/Sprites/santasprites/png', 'Run' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
        img.convert_alpha()  # optimise alpha
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (400, 500))
        img.set_colorkey(BLACK)  # set alpha
        self.running_images.append(img)
for i in range(1, 5):
        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('/home/pi/Desktop/Work/Python work/Game/Resources/Sprites/santasprites/png', 'Walk' + str(i) + '.png')).convert()
        img.convert_alpha()  # optimise alpha
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (400, 500))
        img.set_colorkey(BLACK)  # set alpha
        self.walking_images.append(img)

self.state = 'walk'
self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 400, 500)
```

From the code above, You now have two animation lists. One of running, the other of walking. In order to decide which animation you are on, you need to declare a value, such as `self.state = 'walk'`, which stores whether you're running or walking at the moment. Without it, you would need to recalculate every frame if you're running or walking, which would be a long and slow process

Once you have the lists prepared with their images, the next and final step is to change your update function. Right now, all it does is rotate between the images in your animation list. Now, it not only needs to decide what frame to show in the list, but *also* which list to pick the frames from. Something like this might work:

```
    if self.state == 'walk': images = self.walking_images
    elif self.state == 'run': images = self.running_images

    # moving left
    if self.movex < 0:
        self.frame += 1
        if self.frame > 3*ani:
            self.frame = 0
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(images[self.frame // ani], True, False)

    # moving right
    if self.movex > 0:
        self.frame += 1
        if self.frame > 3*ani:
            self.frame = 0
        self.image = images[self.frame//ani]
```

*Note that up in the first code example, I added `self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 400, 500)`. All the files you are importing are that size, 400x500, so this line works. However, If some of your animation files are a different shape, you will need to redefine the self.rect value. If and when you do that, keep in mind that the position of the character is based off its top left corner, so it will move down and right when you make it taller and wider*